# Pandas DataFrame.apply on object dtype: create new column without affecting used columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to create a new column B by applying a function on each row of column A, which is of data type object and filled with **list** data, in dataframe DF **without** changing the values of column A.

```
def f(i):
 if(type(i) is list):
    for j in range(0,len(i)):
        i[j]+=1
 else:
  i+=1        
 return i
df = pd.DataFrame([1,1],columns=['A'])
df['A']=df['A'].astype(object)
df.at[[0,1],'A']=[1,2]
df['B']=df['A'].apply(lambda x: f(x))
```

Unfortunately the following happens: df['B'] = function(df['A']), but also df['A'] = function(df['A']).

Please note: df['A'] is a **list, dtype is object (o)**.

To be clear: I want column A to remain as original. Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: What does `function` look like? Doesn't `df['A'].apply(function, axis=1)` do what you want?

Comment: function is defined as:
def label(name):        
     for k in concepts.keys():
        if (name in concepts[k]):
            label = "#"+str(k)
    return label

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to include that in a codeblock - it's not particularly readable in comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to use apply on column `A`

```
df['B'] = df['A'].apply(function)
```

this does the function on each value in `A`.

essentially you are using the apply method of the series object, more info:

[pandas.Series.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html)

Comment: With this approach both df['A'] and df['B'] change to function(A), am I missing something here?

Comment: Only df['B'] gets updated with this approach, df['A'] does not change

Comment: note that apply returns a `Series`, it doesn't do operations inplace.
the original info doesn't change.

Comment: please note that column A is a list in df['A'].dtype = object (O). I still get the same result: both A and B change

Comment: you can make a copy of the list in `function`. `if type(name) is list:
     label = name.copy()`

Answer (score 0):

```
df2 = df.copy()
df['B'] = df2.apply(lamba row: function(row['A']), axis=1)
```